# Don't want to re-render even if the state is changed in react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-google-maps

I am using an application that displays a Google map with react Google Maps have multiple pins installed, and the state changes by scrolling, and the active flight changes according to the state.

At that time, the center of the Google map is set to be an activity, but the Google map is re-rendered when the state changes. I don't know how to prevent rendering.

[Google Maps has NPM library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps). It uses react-google-maps and is implemented using hooks. I tried to return false with useEffect (), but I didn't hear it as it is. Please tell me

[image]

MapComponent(HOC)

```
import React from "react";
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, withScriptjs, Marker, InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps";
import { compose, withProps, withHandlers, withStateHandlers } from "recompose";

const MapWithPlaces = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY}&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: "400px", width: "100%" }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: "100%" }} />
  }),
  withStateHandlers(
    props => ({
      infoWindows: props.places.map(p => {
        return { isOpen: false };
      }),
      defaultCenter: { 'lat': props.lat, 'lng': props.lng }
    }),
    {
      onToggleOpen: ({ infoWindows }) => selectedIndex => ({
        infoWindows: infoWindows.map((iw, i) => {
          iw.isOpen = selectedIndex === i;
          return iw;
        })
      })
    }
  ),
  withHandlers(() => {
    const refs = {
      map: undefined,
    }
    console.log(refs);

    return {
      onMapMounted: () => ref => {
        refs.map = ref
      },
      onZoomChanged: ({ onZoomChange }) => (props) => {
        const center = { 'lat': parseFloat(props.lat, 10), 'lng': parseFloat(props.lng, 10) }
        refs.map.pantTo(center)
      }
    }
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={props.zoom} defaultCenter={props.center} key={props.key} ref={map}>
    {props.places &&
      props.places.map((place, i) => {
        let lat = parseFloat(place.lat, 10);
        let lng = parseFloat(place.lng, 10);
        return (
          <Marker
            id={place.id}
            key={place.key}
            position={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
            title={place.name}
            onClick={props.onToggleOpen.bind(this, i)}
            opacity={place.key === props.step ? 1 : 0.5}
            label={place.day === props.currentDay ? place.dayIndex.toString() : ''}
          >
            {props.infoWindows[i].isOpen && (
              <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen.bind(i)}>
                <div>{place.name}</div>
              </InfoWindow>
            )}
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
  </GoogleMap>
));

export default MapWithPlaces;
```

MapComponent(hooks)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { withGoogleMap, withScriptjs, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from "react-google-maps";
// import mapStyles from "./mapStyles";

const MapCreate = React.memo((props) => {
  // const [selectedPark, setSelectedPark] = useState(null);
  const mapRef = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("props updates")
    console.log(props);
    const mapCenter = {
      lat: parseFloat(props.places[props.step].lat, 10),
      lng: parseFloat(props.places[props.step].lng, 10)
    }

    return false
    // refMap.current.panTo(mapCenter) //move the map to new location
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={14} center={{ lat: props.center.lat, lng: props.center.lng }} ref={mapRef}>
      {props.places && props.places.map((place, i) => {
        let lat = parseFloat(place.lat, 10);
        let lng = parseFloat(place.lng, 10);
        return (
          <Marker
            id={place.id}
            key={place.key}
            position={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
            title={place.name}
            opacity={place.key === props.step ? 1 : 0.5}
            label={place.day === props.currentDay ? place.dayIndex.toString() : ''}
          >
          </Marker>
        )
      })}
    </GoogleMap>
  )
})

const MapWrapped = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(MapCreate));

export default function Map(props) {
  const mapRef = useRef(null)
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }}>
      <MapWrapped
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY}`}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: "400px", width: "100%" }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        {...props}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [#shouldcomponentupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
```

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output
>   is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default
>   behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast
>   majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or
>   state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called
>   for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used